# In JACK-Connnections, Yamaha AG06 Interface is listet as ALSA-MIDI not as Audio

Tags: sound, alsa, interface, jack, midi

After programming my Behringer FCB1010 FootController using a Midi-USB-Interface, JackCtl now lists my Yamaha AG06 as a ALSA-MIDI device but AG06 is an audio-interface. Why is this detected wrong and how can I change this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the output of `lsusb -v` for this device.